# Regular expression and Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to regular expression, and I'm wondering how I'd convert an expression such as

```
$a * ($aa - $b)
```

into

```
[a] * ([aa] - [b])
```

I'm using Python's re. Thanks very much!

Comment: So, any string preceded by a dollar sign should be enclosed in square brackets instead?

Comment: If you're wondering, first look at some regular expressions tutorial and try to do it before posting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = '$a * ($aa - $b)'
>>> re.sub(r'\$(\w+)', r'[\1]', strs)
'[a] * ([aa] - [b])'
```